# Ionic2 - What situations require to use a modal instead of a new page?

Tags: ionic2

Can someone explain a situation where using a modal is a better choice than generating a new page? Both of the concepts seem to be the same. New controller, new view etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Going to reference their documentation that clearly explain the difference.

> **Modals** Modals slide in off screen to display a temporary UI, often used for login or signup pages, message composition, and option.A Modal is a content pane that goes over the user's current page. Usually it is used for making a choice or editing an item
>   selection.

And **Pages** are to Display content that require complex logic or have a single purpose

This could be a more UX question ? you can get a answer [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50226/forms-modal-dialog-or-separate-page-in-single-page-app)

Comment: Thanks for the info ;)